# Describing the limit of an ODE at infinity, with oscillatory behaviour

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I have an ODE of the form 
$$ \frac{d}{dt} A(t) = -(1-\lambda)A(t) + B(t), \qquad A(t) \geq 0, B(t) \leq 0$$
I would like to estimate $L$ such that for $0<\lambda < L$,
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} A(t) = 0 \qquad (\star)$$
From this equation I conclude that $L \geq 1$, however this is not tight enough for my liking. I'm expecting $A(t)$ to have some oscillatory behaviour, and this condition only allows monotonic decrease. Is there a way to describe the limiting behaviour of $A(t)$ with ODEs that **does** allow for oscillatory solutions of $A(t)$, but from which I can still conclude ($\star$)? How would such a condition look like in terms of higher order derivatives? I cannot "solve" the ODE but I do have differential equations for higher orders. i.e. $$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} A(t) = f(\lambda)A(t)+g(\lambda)C(t),\qquad C(t)\leq 0 $$

Comment: Is there anything to be said about the behavior of $B(t)$ other than it being less than or equal to zero?

Comment: A differential equation for $B(t)$ can be set up, which has a similar structure to that of the differential equation of $A(t)$.

Comment: If a self-contained set of differential equations can be constructed for your system, then your question might be answered straightforwardly through dynamical systems theory.